# Bootstrap selectpicker VueJS directive

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, directive, vue.js

I'm trying to build a custom directive for Bootstrap that makes a `<select>` input into a "selectpicker" from [Bootstrap selectpicker](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)
Also I would like this directive to use the default `options` functionality of VueJS for filling the options on a `<select>`
So the html would be something like this:

`<select v-selectpicker="myValue" options="myOptions"></select>`

Now I can create the directive perfectly and use the `bind` method to call the `selectpicker()` method on the element. The problem seems to be the fact that the options are set after the call to `selectpicker()`. 
So somehow I need to either wait until the options are set, or I have to do another call to `selectpicker(refresh)` when the options are set.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 5):

The answer provided only works if you're serving your options from the server. Trying to init Bootstrap-select using Vue data as options always has it getting called before the options are rendered.

My solution was to use a component and pass in the options / select name and callback function as props that way I can be sure they are all loaded.

## HTML

```
<select-picker :name.sync="itemsPerPage" :options.sync="itemsPerPageOptions" :function="changeItemsPerPage"></select-picker>
```

## JS - Selectpicker Component

```
Vue.component('select-picker', {
template:'<select v-model="name" class="themed-select" @change="function">' +
'<option v-bind:value="option.value" v-for="option in options">{{ option.label }}</option>' +
'</select>',
name: 'selectpicker',
props: ['options', 'name', 'function'],
updated: function() {
    console.log(this);
    $(this.$el).selectpicker({
        iconBase: 'fa',
        tickIcon: 'fa-check'
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've changed a little solution of mocheaz. It already sets initial value if select tag is placed dynamically:

```js
require('bootstrap-select');

Vue.directive('selectpicker',
{
    twoWay: true,

    bind()
    {
        $(this.el).selectpicker();

        $(this.el).on('change', function(e) {
            this.set($(this.el).val());
        }.bind(this));
    },

    update(newValue)
    {
        $(this.el).val(newValue);
        $(this.el).selectpicker('val', newValue);
    },

    unbind()
    {
        $(this.el).selectpicker('destroy');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Vue.directive('selectpicker',{
inserted:function(el) {     
    jQuery(el).selectpicker({
        title: 'Choose...',
        liveSearch:true,
        dataHeader:"Type in to filter",
        style: 'btn btn-default btn-round',
        size: 10
    }).selectpicker('render');

},
componentUpdated:function(el, binding) {
    jQuery(el).selectpicker('val', binding.value);
    jQuery(el).selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

});

Usage :

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="causeOfLoss" v-selectpicker="causeOfLoss"> ... </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked for me.

```
Vue.directive('selectpicker', {
    twoWay: true,
    bind: function() {
        $(this.el).on("change", function(e) {
            this.set($(this.el).val());
        }.bind(this));
    },
    update: function(nv, ov) {
        $(this.el).trigger("change");
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems it does not set the initial value if <select> is placed dynamically (e.g. in v-for).

Answer (score 0):

this will be useful for those who are looking for the ability to use bootstrap-select and vue.js (v2.5)

Directive:

```
Vue.directive('selectpicker',
{
    inserted(el) {
        $(el).selectpicker(
            {/*options*/},
        });
    },

    update(el, binding) {        
        $(el).selectpicker('val', binding.value);
    },

    componentUpdated(el) {
        $(el).selectpicker('refresh');
    },

    unbindel() {
        $(el).selectpicker('destroy');
    }
});
```

html:

```
<select 
    class="selectpicker form-control" 
    v-selectpicker="mySelectedModel" 
    v-model="mySelectedModel">
    <!-- options -->
</select>
```